# How to avoid redirection of the webcrawler to the mobile edition?

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I subclassed a `CrawlSpider` and want to extract data from website.
However, I always get redirected to the site's mobile version. I tried to change
the `USER_AGENT` variable in scrapy's settings to `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.0.1) Gecko/20060111 Firefox/1.5.0.1`, but still get redirected.

**Is there another way to signal another client and avoid redirection?**

Comment: Could you please show the whole code of your spider (with url you are parsing)?

Comment: In general, when scraping, you should actively announce you are a robot, like the GoogleBot does. I can't think of a situation in which it might be ethical to misrepresent this - can you shed more light on your purpose and the nature of the target site?

Comment: I try to crawl parts of http://derstandard.at/ - however, I always get redirected to it's (express/mobile) version: http://express.derstandard.at/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of redirection supported in [Scrapy](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/downloadermiddleware/redirect.py):

- `RedirectMiddleware` - Handle redirection of requests based on response status
- `MetaRefreshMiddleware` - Handle redirection of requests based on meta-refresh html tag

So, maybe your html page uses second type of redirection?

See also:

- http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#redirectmiddleware-settings
- http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#metarefreshmiddleware-settings